# Sql Get results older than 10 minutes - wpdb Wordpress query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Hi guys i have trouble with a query i need to get the postid's from one column where the posts older than 10 minutes. 
time is a datetime field 2015-03-20 17:15:45
And than i want to work with the id's - (delete them). But i just get an empty array. What im doing wrong? Do i need a for each loop? Im really not good with this. 
Thanks for any help

```
     $getexe = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT postid FROM rejekt WHERE time < DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTES");

   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($getexe);
   echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If time_created is a unix timestamp (int), you should be able to use something like this:

```
SELECT postid FROM rejekt WHERE time < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 600);
```

(600 seconds = 10 minutes - obviously)

Otherwise (if time_created is mysql timestamp), you could try this:

```
SELECT postid FROM rejekt WHERE time < (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
```

Thanks to [Ivar Bonsaksen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/365119/ivar-bonsaksen).

Comment: Thanks for ur help. i saw ivars Post as well but coulndt get it work for my purpose unfortunately i will try it. time is a datetime field 2015-03-20 17:15:45

Comment: thanks mate. but unfortunately not: dont know if its have to do with wordpress maybe?

Comment: Can you please mark this answer as correct. That will help other to solve there problem. Thanks.